# VBA Excel - How can a formula be placed in a range of cells of a body range of a newly added column in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I use this to add Columns in an existing table.

```
position = 1 ' or 5 or 12
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(PREPARE_CALC_SHEET).ListObjects(PREP_CALC_TABLE_NAME)
        .ListColumns.Add Position:= position
        .HeaderRowRange.Value = "Title"
         .ListColumns(position).DataBodyRange.Formula = "=1*9"
End With
```

How do I get the range of the body cells inside the column that I just added?
How can I apply a formula to those column body cells using that range?
I not just want using ".ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Formula = "=1*9"  ", but want to loop through the range of cells.

How can I translate this

```
.ListColumns(position).DataBodyRange
```

to a Range to walk through?

Any suggestions are appreciated

***However the question itself was answered, I do get a Debug dialog on the second line***

```
.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "General"
.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Formula = "=CONCATENATE([@Sort2];[@Sort3];[@Sort4];[@Sort7])"
```

Why?

Comment: `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in .ListColumns(position).DataBodyRange`.... `Next cell`?

Comment: `DataBodyRange` is the range you're looking for

Comment: @BigBen, Thank you; that did it. Please make it an answer and I will make it the solution; if you want of course.

Comment: @TimWilliams - If I use DataBodyRange here, without the ListColumns then it fills the whole table.

Comment: BTW, I did place this formula in there ( all cells are generic ) - .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "General" ; .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Formula = "=CONCATENATE([@Sort2];[@Sort3];[@Sort4];[@Sort7])" , but it shines a big Debug dialog on this line.

Comment: I did mean `.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange` but should have been more explict - I figured since you'd already used that construct it would be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this way:

```
   With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(PREPARE_CALC_SHEET).ListObjects(PREP_CALC_TABLE_NAME)
        .ListColumns.Add Position:=Position
        .ListColumns(Position).name = "Title"
        .DataBodyRange.cells(1, Position).Formula = "=Today()"
    End With
```

Comment: Almost, but I see, I can change this to get it work too. Also thank you.